# trying to copy syntax with "new line" command in bash linux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Trying to copy a syntax with "new lines" command to my terminal  like this one:

```
  qiime tools import \
   --type EMPPairedEndSequences \
   --input-path emp-paired-end-sequences \
   --output-path emp-paired-end-sequences.qza
```

and it get every line as a separate command, so i have to copy them all as separate.

Comment: how did you "copy"?

Comment: Ctrl+C from the browser & Ctrl+Shift+V to the Terminal

Comment: could there be spaces after the backslashes?

Answer (score 1):

The line-continuation will fail if you have whitespace (spaces or tab characters) after the backslash and before the newline. With no such whitespace, your example works fine for me:

```
qiime tools import \
--type EMPPairedEndSequences \
--input-path emp-paired-end-sequences \
--output-path emp-paired-end-sequences.qza
```